# Cómo hago que mi panel con flowlayout no crezca horizontalmente al agregar componentes?

Tags: java

Tengo un panel con flowlayout LEFT dentro de un scrollpane al cual se le agregarán botones al iniciar el programa dependiendo de los productos que hayan en una base de datos, el problema es que cuando los botones llegan al límite derecho del panel en lugar de agregarse a la siguiente fila abajo, se siguen agregando hacia la derecha haciendo crecer el panel así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Encontre en algunos lugares que podia arreglarse utilizando:

```
ScrollCategoria.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Pero solo le quita la barra horizontal al scrollpane pero el panel con los componentes sigue creciendo sin verse hacia la derecha. Ayuda por favor :(

Comment: agrega tu código como texto y no como imagen por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dale a tu panel un tamaño;

```
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
```

siendo WIDTH una constante con el ancho máximo de tu panel y lo mismo con HEIGHT

Comment: Graacias, me ayudaste mucho. Y en caso de que quiera que el height del panel si se agrande automáticamente al agregar botones y llegar al limite inferior, como evito limitar la altura?

Comment: Juega un poco con el tamaño de JFrame y el JPanel, dale diferentes tamaños a width y a height y no tendrás poblema, en cualquier caso, si quieres hable otro hilo con el código para verlo y así poder ayudarte mejor. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por la buena voluntad :), por ahora simplemente lo dejé con un height mas grande no más, lo que más me importaba era limitar el width así que de nuevo muchas gracias, Saludos!